# Windows Phone 7, get apps list + screenshots

Tags: windows-phone-7

1. is there any chance, that (after mango is released) the third-party WP7 application can retrieve list of already installed applications ?
2. Is there possibility to create an application which will take screenshot on background. For example screenshot of mobile main applications list every XY seconds/minutes. I´d like to parse installed applications from that screenshot if point 1 is not possible.

Thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, there is not
2. No, the only way to create WP7 screenshots is from the emulator or with special engineering devices that only MS has

Comment: Thanks, One more question. What about possibility to retrieve apps list after I synchronize my phone with PC. (pc application or via zune)